# API does not get any post data from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data in ajax post call. but this doesnot sent any data.

My html form is

```
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label  for="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input id="firstname" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label  for="lastname">Lastname</label>
        <input id="lastname" type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label  for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input id="subject" type="text" class="form-control" id="subject">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
      <a type="submit" class="btn btn-template-main" onclick="sendMail()"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Send message</a><span id="sentMessage" style="color:green"></span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</form>
```

My script is

```
function sendMail(){
  var name = document.getElementById ("firstname").value + " " + document.getElementById ("lastname").value;
  var subject = document.getElementById ("subject").value;
  var email = document.getElementById ("email").value;
  var message = document.getElementById ("message").value;
  var body = "<h3>Message from "+ name +"</h3>"+
      "<h4>Email: "+ email +"</h4>"+
      "<p><strong>Body : </strong> "+ message +"</p>";
  var email= 'to=tsmrafee@gmail.com&subject=' + subject + '&body=' + body;
  console.log("done");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://trimarkworld.com/email.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      email: email
    },
    success: function(result){
      console.log("done");
      $("#sentMessage").html("Email has been Sent");
    }
  });

}
```

my php code is

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    echo json_decode($_POST['email']);
}
```

This does not print anything..I think there is a problem in the ajax call.please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send data with `$.ajax`, it's not sent as JSON, it's sent in `application/x-www-form-urlencode` format. So there's no need to call `json_decode()`. Just use:

```
echo $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: how can i sent as json? does it need to specify in the headers?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? PHP doesn't want JSON, it won't decode it into `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `json_encode` in your php if your serializing an associative array. Generally I would send back an object, Although in this case if you are just sending a string you don't need to encode the value.

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
  echo json_encode($_POST['email']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP is expecting JSON so you might want to pass stringified JSON.

This example will decode the JSON first, then you can use isset.

Use this example to refactor your code: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-php-ajax-json/